# Angular2 RC2 Forms - Is formGroupName required?

Tags: forms, angular

I updated my Ionic2 application to Beta 9 and Angular2 RC2.  I am in the process of updating my forms, and to start I just tried to get the very simple example to work per https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub.  I am confused about the formGroupName.  The example is:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formGroupName="name">
    <input formControlName="first">
    <input formControlName="last">
  </div>
</form>

class MyComp {
   myForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormGroup({
         first: new FormControl('Nancy'),
         last: new FormControl('Drew')
     })
   });
}
```

The above code works as expected.  My question is whether the "name" grouping is required?  I try to remove it as below and I get the error "Cannot find control 'first'"

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">        
    <input formControlName="first">
    <input formControlName="last">        
</form>

class MyComp {
   myForm = new FormGroup({
      first: new FormControl('Nancy'),
      last: new FormControl('Drew')        
   });
}
```

I didn't expect this behavior.  Will someone please tell me if this is supposed to work and, if not, why?  I am trying to determine if it is a bug or if it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `<div formGroupName="name"` (whole tag) then you don't need to add the group in `new FormGroup`, if you leave it there, then you need the grouping in both HTML and code.